# django redirect to previous url after CreateView

Tags: django, django-forms

I'd like to return to the url of a DetailView(BuildingUnitDetail) that called the CreateView, UpdateView, and DeleteView after a Submit. ex: http://127.0.0.1:8000/unit/13/

I've found several other questions/answers regarding redirects to previous view but I couldn't get any of the solutions to work for me. Mostly because I don't understand them. It seems that it should be a straight forward solution and I'm overthinking them.

Is there a painless solution out there?

Any help would be greatly appeciated, been at this for over 2 days

#urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from cdpapp.views import BuildingList, BuildingDetail, BuildingUnitDetail, CreateWorkOrder, EditWorkOrder, DeleteWorkOrder


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', BuildingList.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^building/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', BuildingDetail.as_view(), name='building_detail'),
    url(r'^unit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', BuildingUnitDetail.as_view(), name='building_unit_detail'),
    url(r'^workorder/add/$', CreateWorkOrder.as_view(), name='workorder_add'),
    url(r'^workorder/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', EditWorkOrder.as_view(), name='workorder_update'),
    url(r'^workorder/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', DeleteWorkOrder.as_view(), name='workorder_delete'),
]
```

#views.py

```
class BuildingUnitDetail(DetailView):
    model = Unit
    template_name = 'cdpapp/building_units_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'units'


class CreateWorkOrder(CreateView):
    template_name = 'cdpapp/workorder_form.html'
    model = WorkOrder
    success_url = reverse_lazy('back to calling url')


class EditWorkOrder(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'cdpapp/workorder_form.html'
    model = WorkOrder
    success_url = reverse_lazy('back to calling url')


class DeleteWorkOrder(DeleteView):
    template_name = 'cdpapp/workorder_form.html'
    model = WorkOrder
    success_url = reverse_lazy('back to calling url')
```

#forms.py

```
class WorkOrderForm(forms.Form):
    building = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Building.objects.all())
    unit = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Unit.objects.all())
    ...
```

#form template

```
{% block content %}
<form method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a next parameter could be an elegant solution.

Here's an example (untested code I just wrote this). Basically using the `get_form_kwargs` method makes sure your button parameter is pushed to the form's initial dict on GET. The `form_valid` method extension makes sure the `success_url` property is overloaded when available in POST data

This way you can still define a default using the `success_url` property in an ordinary fashion.

*note: You cannot trust a user's input. I just used a CharField for the next field for simplicity. In real life you should check the data coming from this field and validate it.*

**BuildingUnitDetail template**

```
<a href="{% url 'workorder_add' %}?next={% url 'building_unit_detail' object.pk %}">
    Add workorder
</a>  <!-- assuming 'object' (Unit) is available in your template's context -->
```

**WorkOrderForm modelform**

```
class WorkOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    next = forms.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = WorkOrder
        exclude = tuple()
```

**CreateWorkOrder view**

```
class CreateWorkOrder(CreateView):
    template_name = 'cdpapp/workorder_form.html'
    form_class = WorkOrderForm
    
    def get_form_kwargs(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super(CreateWorkOrder, self).get_form_kwargs()
        redirect = self.request.GET.get('next')
        if redirect:
            if 'initial' in kwargs.keys():
                kwargs['initial'].update({'next': redirect})
            else:
                kwargs['initial'] = {'next': redirect}
        return kwargs

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        import pdb;pdb.set_trace()  # debug example
        # inspect the errors by typing the variable form.errors
        # in your command line debugger. See the pdb package for
        # more useful keystrokes
        return super(CreateWorkOrder, self).form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        redirect = form.cleaned_data.get('next')
        if redirect:
            self.success_url = redirect
        return super(CreateWorkOrder, self).form_valid(form)
```

**Second thoughts?**

Avoiding redirects, you could also handle these 'tasks' in a popup or handle multiple forms in a single view. This would increase complexity, but the latter *might* enhance user experience.

Comment: almost there i think.  next = forms.CharField(required=False) shows up on the form and has the correct url for redirection. Although when I submit, it neither redirects or saves data.

Comment: @geomajor56 set a breakpoint at the top of the form_valid function and see what the incoming values are. If it isn't getting hit, set a break point in form_invalid and inspect `form.errors`. In case you're new to break points: If you're using the command line debugger you can use `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` to inspect the code (use `c` to continue your code and escape the breakpoint) see the updated example above

Comment: I am new to breakpoints but i'll try to figure it out. I get a page not found error. it saves the data but the redirect error is this       Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/workorder/add/%3Cdjango.template.response.TemplateResponse%20object%20at%200xb5c6e8ac%3E

Comment: That saved data means you hit `form_valid` which is good. See what the next parameter holds, it comes directly from your cleaned form so its value cannot be different than the one you're seeing in your form. I suspect `self.success_url` is overloaded by `get_success_url` somehow.

Comment: originally, i omitted "cleaned_data" in this line redirect = self.cleaned_data.get('next') as my IDE Pycharm said it was  an Unresolved attribute reference. It then saved the data. It also said that 'redirect' "Shadows name 'redirect' from outer scope". Not sure what that means. Am I missing an import for cleaned_data?

Comment: there's your error it should be `form.cleaned_data` hence `self` is the view not the form in this case.

Comment: that did it, thank you so much for your patience as well as help

Comment: Over 2 years later, failing to implement this. kwargs['initial']['next'] is getting the right url in get_form_kwargs(), But form.cleaned_data['next'] is always an empty string ''. Don't see how 'next' value would be pushed into form_cleaned_data. get_form_kwargs is meant to populate the form, no?

Comment: update to above: Accepted solution failed for me, but putting 'self.success_url = redirect' in the get_form_kwargs, not form_valid() got it working.