# Django Generic Based view: not saving HTML form data to database

Tags: django, django-views, django-generic-views

I have a Django library application with several books and authors, here is a /author/create html form used by the admin to create/update details of the author (firstname, lastname, dob, profile picture), referring the MDN Library application.

I have a **Generic Class Based View** for this purpose:

```
 class AuthorCreate(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    permission_required = 'is_superuser'
    model = Author
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('author-detail')


  class AuthorUpdate(PermissionRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    permission_required = 'is_superuser'
    model = Author
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'date_of_birth', 'date_of_death']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('author-detail')

 class AuthorDelete(PermissionRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    permission_required = 'is_superuser'
    model = Author
    success_url = reverse_lazy('authors')
```

And these are the **url patterns**:

```
    urlpatterns += [
path('author/create/', views.AuthorCreate.as_view(), name='author_create'),  # redirects to author_form.html
path('author/<int:pk>/update/', views.AuthorUpdate.as_view(), name='author_update'),  # redirects to author_form.html
path('author/<int:pk>/delete/', views.AuthorDelete.as_view(), name='author_delete'),  # redirects to author_confirm_delete.html
     ]
```

And this is the author_form.html for creating/updating author details:

```
     <form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
      //remaining code...
     </form>
```

Now, on clicking the submit button in the html form above, it should redirect to author/id page(mentioned in the success_url), however the main concern is that **a new author is not getting created in the first place.** 
I am not sure **how the html form data is being saved**, whether or not it is being saved in the first place, because the page is redirecting to the success_url.

Code Referred from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Forms

Comment: You'll need to explain a bit more clearly. What action are you trying to do, create or update? Exactly what URL do you go to in order to see the form, where does it submit to, and where does it redirect to?

Comment: The admin has to create a new author by using the author_form.html, and on clicking the submit button, it should be redirected to a particular page of the author(which is not happening)

Comment: That didn't answer any of my questions.  author_form.html is a template, not a URL. What URL did you go to and what happened? What did you see instead of being redirected? Also, what is in the `//remaining code...` part of that template? Are you displaying validation errors anywhere there?

Comment: on submitting the form, the same author_form.html gets loaded and the authors list does not get updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Author model add,

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
      return reverse('author_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk}) #add kwargs and app_name depending upon your requirement.
```

views.py

```
class AuthorCreate(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    permission_required = 'is_superuser'
    model = Author
    fields = '__all__'

class AuthorUpdate(PermissionRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
   permission_required = 'is_superuser'
   model = Author
   fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'date_of_birth', 'date_of_death']
```

Other way if you are using form in CreateView and UpdateView,

```
def form_valid(self, form):
     self.object = form.save()
     # ....
     return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

If you want to go to previous page only, then [this SO question has an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33585579/django-redirect-to-previous-url-after-createview)